# Binary search program printing false

Tags: java, algorithm

Hello every one i'm working on a binary search program. My algorithm is correct but when I run the program  with the driver program i get back the value "false" repeated instead of a table that looks like this.
[*Table output*(LINK)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioytl.png)

here is my driver program and main program.

```
public class TestResulter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Resulter resulter = new Resulter();
    int numberOfItems = 10000;
    int item;
    int a[ ] = new int[ numberOfItems ];


    for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
    {
        item = Resulter.randomitem( a );
        System.out.println( Resulter.binarySearch( a , item ) );
    }


}

}
```

My main program with binarySearch algorithm.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Resulter extends TestResulter {
private static class Result {
    public Boolean found; // true if found, false if not found
    public int index; // index where item was found, -1 if not found
    public int steps; // number of comparisons performed

    public Result(boolean f, int ind, int st) {
        found = f;
        index = ind;
        steps = st;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Result [found=" + found + ", index=" + index + ", steps=" + steps + "]";
    }
}

public static boolean binarySearch(int[] a, int item) { 
    int start=0, end=a.length-1;
    while(end>=start) { 
        int mid = start + ((end - start) / 2);
        if (a[mid] == item) 
            return true; 
        if (a[mid] > item) 
            end = mid-1; 
        else start = mid+1;
    } 
    return false;
}


public static  int  randomitem ( int[] a ) {
    int i;
    Random random = new Random();
    int item = random.nextInt( 10999 );
    for( i = 0; i < 10000; i++ )
    {
        a[ i ] = random.nextInt( 10000 );
    }
    return item;
}
}
```

I want my program to have a similar output to my image from my linear search program.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that you fill your array `a` with unordered random integers? Binary search only works on sorted arrays.

Comment: pretty much, so how do i get the algorithm work and actually print a table.

Comment: You will have to rework some of your code to assert that the array is sorted after filling it. One further problem is that your `binarySearch` method does not return a `Result` object, but a `boolean`. I will post an answer with some code below.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code with some changes and refactoring:

```
public class TestResulter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int numberOfItems = 10000;
        int item;
        int[] a = new int[numberOfItems];
        fillArray(a);

        for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
        {
            item = Resulter.randomitem(a);
            System.out.println(Resulter.binarySearch(a, item));
        }
    }

    private static void fillArray(int[] a)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            a[i] = random.nextInt(10000);
        Arrays.sort(a);
    }
} 

public class Resulter
{
    private static class Result
    {
        public boolean found; // true if found, false if not found
        public int index; // index where item was found, -1 if not found
        public int steps; // number of comparisons performed

        public Result(boolean f, int ind, int st)
        {
            found = f;
            index = ind;
            steps = st;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Result [found=" + found + ", index=" + index + ", steps=" + steps + "]";
        }
    }

    public static Result binarySearch(int[] a, int item)
    {
        int start=0, end=a.length-1;
        int stepCount = 0;
        while(end>=start)
        {
            stepCount++;
            int mid = start + ((end - start) / 2);
            if(a[mid] == item)
                return new Result(true, mid, stepCount);
            else if(a[mid] > item)
                end = mid-1;
            else
                start = mid+1;
        }
        return new Result(false, -1, stepCount);
    }


    public static int randomitem(int[] a)
    {
        return new Random().nextInt(10000);
    }
}
```

As I see it, the main problems in your solution were:

1. The array was not sorted. Binary search only works on sorted arrays, therefore the `Arrays.sort(a)` command.
2. The `binarySearch` returned a `boolean` and not a `Result` object, which is what you wanted to print out.

Comment: not sure but I have the feeling the method randomitem should return a random item in the array.

Comment: @LeHill I thought, cases where the item cannot be found should be tested, too, i.e. where `Result.found = false`. But you're right, the name of the method suggests what you are saying.

Answer (score -1):

You have a syntax hiccup in your `main` function. Change `int a[]` to `int[] a`.

Also, the logic actions performed in `randomitem` are likely a contributing factor. The `item` it returns which `binarysearch`  uses is not pulled from the search array `a`, but is generated at random. Try `return a[random.nestIng(a.length)];`

I'm on the mobile app, so my syntax may not be perfect.

Comment: so do i add return a[random.nestIng(a.length)]; at the end of the binarysearch method or random item method?

Comment: Replace randomitem's old return statement.

Comment: Now im geting error message telling me the method nestIng(int) is undefined for type random

Comment: Isn't "int a[]" the same as "int[] a"? Both work for me.